# Transparent Bitmap ColorMatrix

Tags: android, bitmap

So my problem is that I want to make my picture Transparent but I get dark Image when I save it. So as I read before I have to change Bitmap ARGB to 0, 0, 0, 0 otherwise it will be black and I will have the same issue. So I did that with:

```
Bitmap.Config config = bmp.getConfig();
    if (config == null) {
        config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    }

    operation = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), config);
    operation.eraseColor(Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

But the thing is that nothing changes. Any ideas why?

My full code:

```
public void brightne(View view) {
    float contrast = 1;
    float brightness = 0;


    Bitmap.Config config = bmp.getConfig();
    if (config == null) {
        config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    }

    operation = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), config);
    operation.eraseColor(Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));

    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(new float[]
            {
                    contrast, 0, 0, 0, brightness,
                    0, contrast, 0, 0, brightness,
                    (float) 0.5, 0, contrast, 0, brightness,
                    0, 0, 0, 1, 0
            });
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(operation);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, contrast, brightness, paint);

    im.setImageBitmap(operation);


}
```

**operation. is my final Bitmap. // bmp. is my picture which I get from Camera.**

Comment: Unclear. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @BobMalooga Just make my final bitmap (operation) white and that's all. Because I'm having issues with Alpha transparency. It makes photos darker.